# How to remove text from before a cursor to start of line in visual mode in vim?

Tags: vim, neovim

I've recently begun challenging myself in VIM and slow to get around still. Suppose I have the following:

```
1   ewdawdawdeditor you can scroll the
  1 page, move the cursor, delete lines, insert
  2 characters, and more, while seeing the
  3 results of your edits as you make them.
```

My cursor is on `1,1` and after `vfe` its on `1,10`.

How can I delete the text before the cursor to the beginning of the line without pressing `hd`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to simply select from the beginning of the line up to but not including the first "e", you can use `vte` instead of `vfe`. Then you can press `d` to delete.

Alternatively, you can delete without entering visual mode with `dte`.

To the extent of my knowledge, I don't think there is a way to delete everything in a visual mode selection excluding the last character.

Comment: Correct. `0dte` is the shortest, though `ted0` isn’t terrible either, if you’ve moved but forgot you wanted to delete. 0 can be exchanged for ^ for slightly different behavior, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If the cursor is somewhere at the middle of a line and you want to delete from the the beginning until the cursor just go with :

```
d^
```

If you really want to go visual before deletion, you can use :

```
v^d
```